# Importing a custom module in Julia returns error

Tags: julia

I have 2 modules and a `.jl` file in my folder.

```
module TreasureHuntEnv

export MapInfo

struct MapInfo
end

end
```

```
module DQNModule

include("./TreasureHuntEnv.jl")
using .TreasureHuntEnv

function runIters(mapInfo::MapInfo)
end

end
```

```
include("./TreasureHuntEnv.jl")
include("./DQN.jl")
using .TreasureHuntEnv
using .DQNModule

function comparisonExperiment(mapInfo::MapInfo)
end

mapInfo = MapInfo()
comparisonExperiment(mapInfo)
```

But when I run the 3rd file, it returns me the following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching runIters(::MapInfo, ::DQN{:dqn}; gameNum=1000, displayInterval=2000, earlyStop=5000, recordQvalues=true)
Closest candidates are:
  runIters(::Main.DQNModule.TreasureHuntEnv.MapInfo, ::DQN; gameNum, stepBeforeLearing, learnInterval, displayInterval, earlyStop, recordQvalues) at e:\Master Thesis\lu_jizhou\Learning\DQN.jl:253
Stacktrace:
 [1] comparisonExperiment(mapInfo::MapInfo)
   @ Main e:\Master Thesis\lu_jizhou\Learning\Experiments.jl:14
 [2] top-level scope
   @ e:\Master Thesis\lu_jizhou\Learning\Experiments.jl:27
```

Why is that and how should I solve the problem?

Comment: You don't need to include `TreasureHuntEnv.jl` in the main code since it is already included from `DQN.jl`.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52713858/13813219

Comment: @JAlex If I remove the `include("./TreasureHuntEnv.jl")` in the 3rd file, it returns me the undefined error `ERROR: UndefVarError: TreasureHuntEnv not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `comparisonExperiment` is meant to have a call to `runIters`, since as is the code you posted works.

The issue is that `include` in the second module is essentially copying all the code for the first module, which then produces a *submodule* `DQNModule.TreasureHuntEnv`, which explains your error message.

One way to avoid the problem is to export `DQNModule` and this submodule in your script:

```
include("DQN.jl")
using .DQNModule
using .DQNModule.TreasureHuntEnv

function comparisonExperiment(mapInfo::MapInfo)
    DQNModule.runIters(mapInfo)
end

mapInfo = MapInfo()
comparisonExperiment(mapInfo)
```

Personally I would recommend sticking to `include` statements rather than formal modules at first, then creating [packages](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/creating-packages/) for your modules once you are ready

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I turned to @Vitaliy Yakovchuk's solution here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64372573/error-occurred-when-loading-a-custom-julia-module" about how to manage multiple custom modules in a project.